# how can i get the error code "os.ErrNotExist" from the error itself?

Tags: go, error-handling

This code can be run here: https://play.golang.org/p/dX6dOzWS-Gx

```
cachedirstring := "./cache"
_, err = os.Stat(cachedirstring)
if err != nil {
    if errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", err)
    }
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

This outputs:

```
*fs.PathError
```

I know to use `errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist)` from a book.  My question is, how could I know that `errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist)` would return `true` (through code, rather than a search engine) ?

How can I find all target errors that would equal `err` ?

Comment: *"How can I find all target errors that would equal 'err'?"* -- By reading the documentation, by reading the source code, and through experience.

Comment: mkopriva, thanks; i did look through the docs quite a bit.  but i was only able to find `errnotexist` by already knowing about it.  `go doc os errnotexist | grep -i errnotexist` yielded results while `go doc os | grep -i errnot` yielded no results.  so what pages do you suggest i peruse?

Comment: I suggest the you to read the documentation of the function you're using, if its authors deemed it important to know the specific error type that that function can return then they have probably mentioned it in the documentation. If it is considered unimportant then there's no reason to explicitly list every possible error on every function.

Comment: "How can I find all target errors that would equal err ?" You simply cannot. That's not how it works. For each error you can read the doc and see what it provides or doesn't provide and what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly emulate what [errors.Is](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is) does "on paper":

- Check what looping through the chain of errors would do, when the [erros.Unwrap](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Unwrap) method is called on it.
- For each error, consider whether it is `==` to the target, or if it implements the `Is(error) bool` method and would return true for it.

For example, [this line](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/syscall/syscall_unix.go;l=133;drc=7bb721b9384bdd196befeaed593b185f7f2a5589) makes `errors.Is(..., os.ErrNoExist)` true for the `syscall.Errno` type if it has the right error code.